# Vlookup not matching what it should

Tags: excel, vlookup

What I am trying to do is simple and therefore it confuses me why does not work so my plan is to compare two columns in excel and display the match in a separate Colum a typical vlookup exercises.

My issue is that does not match correctly only on the first one is correct.

Column D First Sheet

```
+-------+
| ColD  |
+-------+
| SA212 |
| SA912 |
| .     |
| SA211 |
+-------+
```

Column A Second Sheet

```
+-------+
| ColA  |
+-------+
| SA212 |
| SA912 |
| .     |
| SA211 |
+-------+
```

My Vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(D:D;Table_owssvr[Project number];1)
```

What happens is simple that the the "matches" are not right instead of matching SA212 to SA212 it matches it to SA912 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last argument ([range_lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel)) to `false`, or `0`. Otherwise you are asking for an approximate match.

```
=VLOOKUP(D:D;Table_owssvr[Project number];1;0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not seem to work, the "error" #VALUE! appears now

Comment: @Niko.K Fixed: 0 should be the 4th and last argument, not the 3rd argument.